# How can I select using jQuery 'select' tag with determined selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For instance,

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <select>
        <option value="en" selected="selected">english</option>
        <option value="ar">العربية</option>
        <option value="az">azərbaycanlı</option>
        <option value="bg">български</option>
        <option value="ca">català</option>
        <option value="cs">český</option>
        <!-- some data cut -->
    </select>
<select>
        <option value="en" >english</option>
        <option value="ar">العربية</option>
        <option value="az" selected="selected">azərbaycanlı</option>
        <option value="bg">български</option>
        <option value="ca">català</option>
        <option value="cs">český</option>
        <!-- some data cut -->
    </select>
<select>
        <option value="en" >english</option>
        <option value="ar">العربية</option>
        <option value="az" selected="selected">azərbaycanlı</option>
        <option value="bg">български</option>
        <option value="ca">català</option>
        <option value="cs">český</option>
        <!-- some data cut -->
    </select>
</div>
```

How can I select `'select'` tag with `value="az"`

I've found the only  way:

```
var val_ = "az";
    var selects = $div.find("select").filter(function(index_){
                var val0 = $(this).val();
                return val0 == val_;
            });
```

Is there more elegant way to do it?

**EDIT.** My question is about 'select' tag. All of questions in stackoverflow is about child 'option' tag.

Comment: lol. now. The link explains how to work with options. please, read more carefully.

Comment: @Burk ,  you made an error. You didn't understand my question if you attaches this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use attribute equals selector **[`[attribute='value']`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**,for selecting using  particular value
2. Use **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** selector for checking selected option value
3. **[`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)** selector for getting selected option

**CODE:**

```
$('select:has(:selected[value="az"])')
```

With variable you can

```
var val_ = "az";
var selects = $('select:has(:selected[value="' + val_ + '"])');
```

For example :

```js
var val_ = "az";
$('select').change(function() {
  var selects = $('select:has(:selected[value="' + val_ + '"])');
  console.log(selects.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <select>
    <option value="en" selected="selected">english</option>
    <option value="ar">العربية</option>
    <option value="az">azərbaycanlı</option>
    <option value="bg">български</option>
    <option value="ca">català</option>
    <option value="cs">český</option>
    <!-- some data cut -->
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="en">english</option>
    <option value="ar">العربية</option>
    <option value="az" selected="selected">azərbaycanlı</option>
    <option value="bg">български</option>
    <option value="ca">català</option>
    <option value="cs">český</option>
    <!-- some data cut -->
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="en">english</option>
    <option value="ar">العربية</option>
    <option value="az" selected="selected">azərbaycanlı</option>
    <option value="bg">български</option>
    <option value="ca">català</option>
    <option value="cs">český</option>
    <!-- some data cut -->
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not answer OP, he is asking for an optimized version of the code that he written already. `Is there more elegant way to do it?`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy :  I think, this will be better than his code

Comment: Yeah you finally made it after some ~32 edits. congrats. Now it can answer OP's question.

Comment: @PranavCBalan , is there any solution without ':selected' option.  select tag are update their child as selected.

Comment: in that case you should use filter

Comment: @PranavCBalan, thanks.

Comment: @trololo : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can select one or more `<select>` elements containing an `<option>` with the value "az" like so:

```
$("select option[value='az']")
```

Comment: no. You will select 'option' child. Not the parent.